# Increment column using update OR create a on update trigger - mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, triggers, sql-update

I have to increment column D when column A or B or C gets updated (In same table).
1. Should I use another update statement to increment column D after A, B or C gets updated OR
2. Should I use a trigger ?

Which is the better and faster way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a trigger. That is what they are for.